# Почему появилась директория lost+found на отформатированном диске в чистом Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ext4, fstab

Установлен чистый Ubuntu сервер версии 20.
Два HDD переразмечены утилитой fdisk:

- удалены все разделы
- созданы таблицы GPT
- созданы разделы во весь диск

Разделы форматированы `mkfs.ext4`

В `fstab` добавлены эти диски по аналогии с теми, что прописал установщик:

```
UUID="4b150022-4e47-471b-82d2-9fe8d879cf22" /mnt/toshiba ext4 defaults 0 0
UUID="b8b70c16-911b-4a51-8320-2e046de83b0d" /mnt/hgst ext4 defaults 0 0
```

Ожидалось, что диски будут стоять молча, но после монтирования на них началась активность и появились директории `lost+found`. Отмонтировать диски нельзя, потому что они заняты.

Откуда появилась активность и эти директории на чистой системе и чистых дисках?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как уже сказано `lost+found` — служебный каталог для «потерянных и найденных» файлов, в который `fsck` складывает оные. Он создаётся при создании ФС.

А активность (запись) на дисках может быть, например, связана с тем что:

- При монтировании в режиме на чтение/запись обновляется время последнего монтирование в суперблоке ФС.
- При просмотре файлов/каталогов на носителе обновляется время последнего доступа к файлам.

Answer (score 5):

Это служебные директории и в линуксе они автоматически создаются на каждом диске, даже на внешних. Они используются утилитой fsck, которая проверяет целостность файловой системы. Если  ходе проверки найдутся поврежденные файлы и "ничейные" данные, то они будут помещены в lost+found.

Comment: На каждом диске с файловой системой ext2/ext3/ext4 (возможно, и с ещё какими-то).